# Make the Status, Visibility, or Date fields opened by default in the Publish box

Tags: admin, metabox, editor, publish

By default, the Status, Visibility, and Date fields in the Publish metabox are closed, and you have to click **Edit** to show them.

Is there a way to make these fields visible by default?

The hidden elements all have a class of `hide-if-js`.

Comment: You can figure out their respective containers' id using any DOM inspector and set their visibility in CSS file or using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery code seems to work, when added via the `admin_footer` hook.

- `#submitdiv` = the whole Publish metabox
- `.misc-pub-section` = each UI section (except the Publish and Save sections)
- `.hide-if-js` = the fields that are hidden by default

  ```
  $('#submitdiv .misc-pub-section')
      .has("#post-status-display, #timestamp")
      .find('.hide-if-js')
      .toggle();
  ```

That will unhide the **Status** dropdown and the **Date** picker.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @supertrue 's answer, here is a full implementation.

1./ Create a .js file (for ex: `admin-post-ui-visibility.js`) containing the following:

```
(function($){

    $('#submitdiv .misc-pub-section')
        .has("#post-status-display, #timestamp")
        .find('.hide-if-js')
        .toggle();

})(jQuery);
```

2./ Add this to your Theme's functions.php file:

```
function reveal_visibility_metabox($hook){
    if( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'reveal_visibility_metabox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/library/js/admin-post-ui-visibility.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'reveal_visibility_metabox' );
```